# Why would Xcode not find my customized UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: swift, xcode6, uicollectionviewcell, iboutlet

Any ideas why Xcode doesn't recognize or 'see' my customized UICollectionViewCell class?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the class in the same module? Have you tried rebuilding the project?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in XCode, I've run into it for no reason, and had it start working later on.

The work around is to type out your outlet in the swift file first:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView:UIImageView!
```

Then compile and drag from the swift file to interface builder.